# Visualforce display a related list from a lookup field on a custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, class, related-list

I am quite new to salesforce/coding and got myself stuck on a stumbling block when developing object for our internal use.

I have and object called **Inventory_Skid_c** this object has a field called Skid Location that is a lookupfield to another object called **WH_Bin**.
So my issue is the following I want to display another object that is related to **WH_Bin** as a related list in this page this is object is named **Stock_Levels__c**

Under the WH_Bin I can see as a related list all the stock levels records and I want this information pertaining only this Bin to be show on the Inventory Skid object.

I tried to google and solve using only visual force but it seems impossible so I tried to do on the sandbox using a controller and visualforce but im pretty much stuck

Here is the code I have for the controller:

```
public class WarehouseBinChildController{
  list<WH_Warehouse_Bins__c> cons = [
    Select Id,
    Name,
    (SELECT Id FROM Stock_Levels__c)
    FROM WH_Warehouse_Bins__c

  ];
}
```

for the visual force I'm completely lost how to write the apex for it.
[image: Stock level reference image]

Below is the schema, sorry it took me some time to figure out how to get this view:
[image]

**EDIT**
Error I am getting with the code:
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you are not considering LWC instead of VF?  Also, please use [edit] and show a diagram of the schema w/ sample records to explain what you want to show

Comment: I have no idea what is LWC, in summary I want to display only the stock level records related to the bin that the user selected on the field called skid location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without any Apex controller just by exploiting the standardController for `Inventory_Skid__c`

```
<apex:page standardController="Inventory_Skid__c">

  <apex:relatedList 
     list="Stock_Levels__r"
     subject="{!Inventory_Skid__c.Skid_Location__c}"  
   />
</apex:page>
```

*where*

- `list` is the API name of the related list from parent to child
- `subject` evaluates to an ID field that is the parent of the related list

References

- [VF RelatedList component reference doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm)
- [Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000096MeIAI)

Comment: Oh really? cool, gonna try and reply back asap. Thanks for the support

Comment: Humm, gives me an error when I put the code below:
**Error: Formula expression is required for attribute subject in <apex:relatedList> in InventorySkidVF2 at line 3 column 91**

<apex:page standardController="Inventory_Skid__c">

  <apex:relatedList subject="Inventory_Skid__c.Skid_Location__c" list="Stock_Levels__r" />

</apex:page>

Comment: Fixed. Forgot the merge field expression

Comment: even with the ! still complains about **Error: Formula expression is required for attribute subject in <apex:relatedList> in InventorySkidVF2 at line 3 column 91**.

Comment: I removed the comments which were causing some parsing issues; I tested the exact example for the above in my org and it compiles and works fine

Comment: Humm, I think is some issue on my side salesforce then because still happens, I have added a screenshot on the main post

Comment: you are missing the enclosing `{..}` on the subject attribute

Comment: Amazing! I feel so bum now... thank a lot saved me! Guess ill research now how to control the display it better!